# Social login keeps the provider app logged in

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, google-signin, social-authentication

1. I visit an app that uses oauth social login
2. I choose say gmail; I get sent to gmail site
3. I log in to gmail and then get sent back to the app
4. When done with the app I log out

After step 4, even if I close the browser and open anew, visiting gmail opens my account straight away without prompting for a password. Keep in mind, I never let browsers save my password neither do I ever tick “remember me”

I’m not sure the average user will remember to visit gmail separately to log out; this would be disastrous on a public computer.

My question:

Is this a design flaw of oauth2 or is it an implementation flaw with the app in step 1 or is it an implementation flaw with google-login? Or is it technically impossible for the app in step 1 to log out of the social identity provider (in which case it’s not a flaw at all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenID Connect core spec and the session management spec defines ways to both:

- Sign the user out of an identity provider ([link](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html))
- And force user re-authentication with the OP after a maximum
  authentication age (`max_age`) has elapsed since last user
  authentication. ([link](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ServerMTI))

  Trouble is I'm not sure if Google implement these things [see this](http://lists.openid.net/pipermail/openid-specs-ab/Week-of-Mon-20150323/005445.html)

I've tagged your question with `OpenID Connect` as authentication is not an OAuth2.0 concern.

Comment: So google feels their sophisticated systems will automatically sense it the user is on a public system and re-auth. Ok.